# Mercurial wrongfully shows new files (really already pushed)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a mercurial version control installation in my company. We have central repository and regularly pull changes from there.
Several files on my computer are marked as newer ones. But really they already exist there.
If I delete them physically, they became marked as removed. If I revert them, they become newer ones.
I already tried to reload this repository to newer place, but situation was repeated.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like you're pulling but not updating.

Pulling gets the changesets others have made, but they don't become active in your code directory until you update to them.

If I've misunderstood, could you post a sequence of commands, with the output you get, to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Of course I am pulling and updating every day or even every hour. I dont know how to show commands, I use TortoiseHG.

I saw unversioned file. I know that really it lays on the server, but I delete it from disk (by TortoiseHG or by file manager).
After refresh it becomes as "removed".
I revert changes about this file. It becomes unversioned again

Comment: I've seen weird behaviour like this before if a file is in the repository but is also listed in your `.hgignore`. Can you check whether that's the case? It's possible that TortoiseHg isn't interacting with `.hgignore` the way it should be.

Comment: No, .hgignore is not contain these files.

Comment: What version of Tortoise and what version of Mercurial do you have? An upgrade could fix this. Or, if you're on the bleeding edge version, a downgrade to the latest stable release.

Comment: I have changed different versions. Now Mercurial is 2.2.2 and TortoiseHg is 2.4.1,

Answer (score 0):

If you miss icon overlays for *some files*, you can try TortoiseHG - Update Icons (or just `cd` forward and back some time, restart Overlay Icon Server...)

If you miss icon overlays for all files of *some type*, you may reach limit of overlays for your OS (bundle of different Tortoise* can give such effect)